# Retrofit, Object inside Array is null

Tags: android, arrays, json, rest, retrofit2

I have already use `Retrofit` with `Google API`, and there is no problem, but since I use my own API, I got a trouble.

So, first, this is my json response

```
{
  "channel": "HBO HD",
  "date": "2016-09-08",
  "items": [
    {
      "film_name": "Dead Again",
      "film_plot": null,
      "show_time": "01:35:00"
    },
    {
      "film_name": "Zeus and Roxanne",
      "film_plot": null,
      "show_time": "03:20:00"
    }
  ],
  "response": "Complete"
}
```

well, there is 12 items inside the `array` items.

and I am using `jsonschema2pojo.org` to make the class

And here is my `Retrofit` to retrieve the data

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())//GsonConverter untuk parsing json
            .build();
    RestApi service = retrofit.create(RestApi.class);
Call<ScheduleList> call = service.getScheduleList2
call.enqueue(new Callback<ScheduleList>() {
@Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ScheduleList> call, Response<ScheduleList> response) {
            try {
                loading.dismiss();
                Log.d(TAG, "get Channel: " + response.body().getChannel());
                Log.d(TAG, "get Date: " + response.body().getDate());
                Log.d(TAG, "get Response: " + response.body().getResponse());
                Log.d(TAG, "get Item: " + response.body().getItems());
                List<Item> test = response.body().getItems();
                Log.d(TAG, "size Array Item size: " + test.size());
                Log.d(TAG, "get Film Name inside array Item: " + response.body().getItems().get(0).getFilmName());
```

in result in log for `getChannel, getDate, getResponse` is good.
but, in `getDataSchedule` is Item@b4fdbe3, Item@a91f9e0.
The size is returning the correct number of array size.
But if I try to get the `FilmName`, the log shows null.

This is the class that I use to parse the response.

```
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class ScheduleList {

private String channel;
private String date;
private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
private String response;
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The channel
 */
public String getChannel() {
    return channel;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param channel
 *     The channel
 */
public void setChannel(String channel) {
    this.channel = channel;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The date
 */
public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param date
 *     The date
 */
public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The items
 */
public List<Item> getItems() {
    return items;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param items
 *     The items
 */
public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
    this.items = items;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The response
 */
public String getResponse() {
    return response;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param response
 *     The response
 */
public void setResponse(String response) {
    this.response = response;
}

public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}
}
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Item {

private String filmName;
private Object filmPlot;
private String showTime;
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The filmName
 */
public String getFilmName() {
    return filmName;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param filmName
 *     The film_name
 */
public void setFilmName(String filmName) {
    this.filmName = filmName;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The filmPlot
 */
public Object getFilmPlot() {
    return filmPlot;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param filmPlot
 *     The film_plot
 */
public void setFilmPlot(Object filmPlot) {
    this.filmPlot = filmPlot;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The showTime
 */
public String getShowTime() {
    return showTime;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param showTime
 *     The show_time
 */
public void setShowTime(String showTime) {
    this.showTime = showTime;
}

public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}
}
```

How could this happen? I dont get what I've done wrong, thanks for helping.

Comment: What do you mean with "the size is true"?

Comment: And can you post the class you are using to parse the response please?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't made changes in the json or in the response class after having used jsonschema2pojo?

Comment: @kingston the size is true I mean that the test.size() return the correct number of amount the size of item array.

Comment: @kingston hey, you can use this link [link]http://homecinema.pe.hu/api/v1/schedule?daftar_channel=HBO%20HD&date_now=2016-09-08 to test. And Im sure that I haven't made changes in the json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used org.jsonschema2pojo but I guess that Gson cannot parse the film_name in JSON to filmName. Try adding this annotation to the filmName property

```
class Item {
    @SerializedName("film_name")
    private String filmName;
     ...
}
```